# User defined system variable throws null pointer exception when executed as testng suite

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, pom.xml

There has been a situation when I need to run with the user defined *`<systemPropertyVariables>`* in one of my utility class.

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
<environment>uat</environment>                      
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

I have defined this in my pom.xml file.

inside my utility class I am extracting this value using below

```
System.getProperty("environment");
```

When I run the test case through pom.xml it runs fine. But when I try to run it through testing.xml file or as a testng test, it gives me nullpointerException.

I have defined vmarguments in run configuration as a temp solution but when this code gets distributed again this won't work as run configuration is limited to the local machines.

Can anyone please help me on how to resolve this error. Where should I define the SystemPropertyVariable so that it also works when I run the testng suite individually.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is pass this values from testNG using parameter tag and you can retrieve these values in Test class. By this you can run this both from maven and testng

Comment: make sense, but i only needed testng runs for debugging purpose.
that was the first solution that hit. but was not very useful. 

when the suite gets executed on vm its from command line argument.
I have written a core java code to handle that.

Comment: even if the suite gets triggered from the command line your testng will have parameters and will run accordingly or you can handle it in code checking if no parameters from maven then use testng parameters

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found a solution for this if any one else is stuck with this type of problem while designing framework.

Write a simple java code

```
try{
your code
}catch(NullPointerException ee){
environment="";
e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
Assert.assertTrue(fail);
}
```

it only handles your code when you run via testng.xml (which is not part of your major test runs) and fails when we get any other exceptions.